# how to load Moving Average weight variable at inference phase with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to use the moving average model weight at inference phase, I know how to use `tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage`, but I don't know how to save the moving average weight variables (also biases) and load them during inference time instead of using the final trained values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to used the build-in [`tf.contrib.opt.MovingAverageOptimizer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/opt/MovingAverageOptimizer), that wraps your optimizer, and produces a variable saver that swaps variables with their moving averages.

Example from the docs:

```
// Encapsulate your favorite optimizer (here the momentum one)
// inside the MovingAverageOptimizer.
opt = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate, FLAGS.momentum)
opt = tf.contrib.opt.MovingAverageOptimizer(opt)
// Then create your model and all its variables.
model = build_model()
// Add the training op that optimizes using opt.
// This needs to be called before swapping_saver().
opt.minimize(cost, var_list)
// Then create your saver like this:
saver = opt.swapping_saver()
// Pass it to your training loop.
    slim.learning.train(
        model,
        ...
        saver=saver)
```